# Home Network- setting up new wireless router with existing dsl modem/router

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

Been using a modem/router provided by my DSL ISP for a while now. Got a Ring Pro doorbell, which connects via wireless. Was having problems with that, and while resolving all that, discovered that my ISP-provided modem (Actiontec C1000a) was no longer being updated with firmware, and the wireless wasn't that good to begin with.

Ok, so I bought a Netgear Nighthawk R7000p. I have an ethernet wire from the actiontec to the nighthawk. Turned off wireless on actiontec. Turned on wireless on the nighthawk. Things work great. Much stronger, faster signal everywhere. Hooray!

But now I have a few questions. The actiontec is accessed via 192.168.0.1, the standard. The nighthawk is 192.168.1.1. Things work fine, but the only problem i see right now is that wireless devices connected to the nighthawk can't see devices hardwired to the actiontec. Right now this isn't a problem per se, but in the near future i plan on getting a new smarttv for the basement and would like to hardwire it. The way the wiring is set up, it'd be FAR easier to wire it to the actiontec. Now if I'd do something like a plex server or whatever, the nighthawk wouldn't see it, correct?

Searches and info from the Ring tech support etc say I should be disabling DHCP on that actiontec, some say set it as a "transparent bridge" etc. But wouldn't the bridge make it no longer act as a router too? I kinda need that, but if need be i can buy another switch or something if it helps.

See the diagram:
[image: Current Network Setup]

Some more details:

1. The smarthub and bluray player are hardwired to the nighthawk. Smarthub- that's the only option, no wireless. BluRay is for performance.
2. To improve the performance of the ring doorbell, we gave it a static
   IP with the nighthawk. Would like to keep that.
3. The actiontec is in    the basement office. I set up a structured media center where all
   network cables come into a single cabinet. The office then has the
   phone line and 3 network ports available. I run the phone to the
   actiontec, plug my PC directly into it, and then from another port
   run a line back to the media center. From there it's patched to the
   line that runs upstairs to the TV, behind which is the Nighthawk. The
   big problem is there is only one line there, or i'd just run one back
   down to the media cabinet and hook everything off the nighthawk
   there. If it turns out that's the best thing, i'll do it, but that's
   some tricky wire pulling.

So, the question is, what is the best way to configure all this? It is all working right now, but i'd like to do it right and have the abilities mentioned above in the future.

Comment: so devices IP's for the devices connected from actiontech and nighthhawk have same subnet or different subnet? Not the webpaga admin, but the IP itself on the hosts.

Comment: i believe so. Actiontec was giving nighthawk a static ip (192.168.0.45), and i went and changed the nighthawk to use a static ip and the subnet of 255.255.255.0. They're both using that subnet now. I can now, from my laptop connected wirelessly to nighthawk, navigate to the actiontec admin panel, which i couldn't do before. but i can't go to the nighthawk's panel from my pc hardwired to actiontec. hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is a bit unique, and the techs you have talked to are not answering the correct problem.

The best way to ensure interconnectivity of all devices would be to merge the two networks together so that there is a single layer 2 LAN. Currently, this is not the case, since your Nighthawk is doing routing, firewalling, etc.

First, disable the DHCP server entirely on one of the devices, and remove the static WAN IP address that you already configured (you can disable the WAN). Set the Nighthawk's LAN address to something within your Actiontec's range. Then, take the cable that is currently running from the Actiontec to the Nighthawk's WAN port, and move it to a LAN port. At this point, the Nighthawk is acting just like a wired/wireless switch and is no longer performing any routing, and you are left with a single subnet that allows communication between all devices.

Comment: To make sure the wireless on the Nighthawk is seamless you can keep the DHCP here just make it a range that is not done by the Actiontek. I have an older router used in this manner for extra wireless coverage as well as using the LAN ports as switch ports for an entertainment center. I put my router at 192.168.0.254 and made the 192.168.0.1 the gateway like your Actiontec

Comment: @KevinK that doesn't match up with my answer, nor what the asker wants

Comment: Didn't work. Can't set the LAN in my actiontec range because i get a "The IP address conflicts with the WAN IP subnet. Please enter a different IP address." message and it won't let me change it. If i remove the cable from the actiontec to the nighthawk, i can see everything on the network, except i can no longer get into the nighthawk's admin page to remove the static wan, etc.

Comment: That's why you need to disable the WAN before setting the LAN address.

Comment: disable the wan- is that a setting or just taking the cable out? because there is no setting to do that.

Comment: On most consumer routers I've seen, for the WAN addressing,  you can choose between DHCP, static, disabled and some other options. If you can't disable it, leave it on DHCP or set it to an address on an unused private range.

Comment: This KB article may apply to your specific device https://kb.netgear.com/24104/How-do-I-change-my-Nighthawk-router-to-AP-mode-after-I-ve-already-run-setup